# calculate $\lim _{n\to \infty}\sum _{ k=1 }^{ n }{ \left| { e }^{ \frac { 2\pi ik }{ n } }-{ e }^{ \frac{ 2 \pi i(k-1) }{ n }} \right|}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

$\lim _{ n\to \infty  } \sum _{ k=1 }^{ n }{ \left| { e }^{ \frac { 2\pi ik }{ n }  }-{ e }^{ \frac { 2\pi i(k-1) }{ n }  } \right|  } $

We know that $e^{i\pi}=-1$ $\rightarrow$ $e^{2i\pi}=1$ $\rightarrow$ $e^{2i\pi k}=1$, $e^{2i\pi(k-1)}$= $\frac{e^{2i\pi k}}{e^{2i\pi}}=\frac{1}{e^{2i\pi }}=1$. Then

\begin{align}
\lim_{n\to \infty} \sum _{k=1}^{n} \left| e^{\frac{ 2\pi ik }{ n }}  -e^{ \frac { 2\pi i(k-1) }{ n }  } \, \, \, \right| &= \lim _{n\to \infty} \sum _{ k=1 }^n \left| (e^{ 2\pi ik })^{ 1/n }-(e^{ 2\pi i(k-1) })^{ 1/n } \right| \\
&=\lim _{n\to \infty} \sum _{ k=1 }^n \left| (1)^{1/n}-(1)^{1/n} \right| =0 
\end{align}

I am not convinced by the result. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 2):

Noting
$$\sum _{ k=1 }^{ n }{ \left| { e }^{ \frac { 2\pi ik }{ n }  }-{ e }^{ \frac { 2\pi i(k-1) }{ n }  } \right|}=\sum _{ k=1 }^{ n }\bigg|{ e }^{ \frac { 2\pi i(k-1) }{ n }}\bigg|{ \left| { e }^{ \frac { 2\pi i }{ n }  }-1 \right|}=\sum _{ k=1 }^{ n }\sqrt{2(1-\cos(\frac { 2\pi}{ n }))}=2n\sin(\frac {\pi}{ n }) $$
one has
$$ \lim_{n\to\infty}\sum _{ k=1 }^{ n }{ \left| { e }^{ \frac { 2\pi ik }{ n }  }-{ e }^{ \frac { 2\pi(k-1) }{ n }  } \right|}=\lim_{n\to\infty}2n\sin(\frac { \pi}{ n })=2\pi. $$

Comment: I believe the absolute value for $\left|e^{\frac{2\pi\pi i}{n}} - 1\right|$ should be the square root of the expression you got.

Comment: Yes, you are right. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Consider these as points in the complex plane. Each value $e^{2\pi ik/n}$ is a vertex of a regular $n$-gon centered at $0$ with all vertices lying on the unit circle, and your sum is just the perimeter of this $n$-gon. As $n\to\infty$, the sides approximate the circumference of the unit circle, giving an answer of $2\pi$.